# Passing buttons between View Controllers in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, viewcontroller

I am wanting to know how to pass buttons between two view controllers. As an example when you click "move" on one view controller the button will appear on another view controller. I am wanting to know the code to do this task. Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me but... that's something veeeery weird. Why not creating a new button on the second view controller? That is the "normal" way of doing it. Is there a special reason you want to do this?

Comment: well the project that i am creating requires this to happen because it allows the user to pick what button they want. the buttons will have different actions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just make an identical button of that button. When you click the "move" button the next screen will have the "move" button. Except this time it will have the functionality of your choice!

Comment: Is there anyway i can change the image of the button from a different view controller from another button